# Request forbidden by administrative rules error for Heroku custom domain

Tags: heroku, dns

I create a Heroku Java web application. I added pointDNS account to forward `*.herokuapp.com` domain to my custom domain. Forwarding is succesful and I can open my heroku application by using my custom domain. `example.com` and `www.example.com` are working. But sometimes when I open `example.com` it gives this error :

```
{
  "message": "Request forbidden by administrative rules",
  "__type": "CloudSearchException"
}
```

or

```
Cannot GET /
```

Also I can see H27 error in Heroku account. But at this time if I open `www.example.com` it is working.

I check ip from chromium developer tools and I see that
`example.com` and `www.example.com` is going to a different IP address. I used google dig for all ip for `example.com` and try all of them in browser. some of ip gives same error. Is this heroku bug or because of I set wrong rules for DNS? How can I resolve "Request forbidden by administrative rules" error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pointDNS resolved my issue. I am using pointDNS to set dns rules for my custom domain. I asked them about issue. They said that there are some outdated record in my account. issue was fixed when they removed them

Comment: Which records were causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a configuration error, but more of a firewall kind of rule triggering which is blocking the access.

Check if you are not making too many requests, which is considered as fake or aggressive crawling and the ip getting blocked.